# Is there a way to escape and use ColdFusion query reserved words as column names in a query of query?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm working with a query that has a column named "Date."

The original query returns okay from the database. You can output the original query, paginate the original query, get a ValueList of the Date column, etc.

**Query of Query**

```
<cfquery  name= "Query" dbtype= "query">
select 
[Query].[Date]

from [Query] 

</cfquery>
```

**Response from ColdFusion**

> Query Of Queries syntax error. Encountered "Date. Incorrect Select
>   List,

Typically, I use descriptive names so I haven't run across this issue previously.

In this case, I'm working with a stored procedure that someone else wrote. I ended up modifying the stored procedure to use a more descriptive column name.

I have a service I use for transforming, searching and sorting queries with ColdFusion. I'm curious to know the answer to my original question, so that I can modify my service to either throw a better error or handle reserved words.

Is there a way to escape and use ColdFusion query reserved words as column names in a query of query?

Comment: It works for me as well (CF9). But in answer to the original question, I do not know that it is as flexible as escaping in a db query. For example `[Column With Spaces]` still throws an error under CF9. So you may just want to throw a more descriptive error.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that about columns with spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code works fine for me:

```
<cfset query = queryNew("date")>

<cfdump var="#query#">

<cfquery  name= "Query" dbtype= "query">
select 
[Query].[Date]

from [Query] 

</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#query#">
```

Comment: Copying response from G+.

Thanks Sam,

The brackets do work to escape reserved words. I simply wasn't noticing the line numbers changing on the error after putting them into place.

I had a secondary function building out a similar select for another query of query. I found it trying to put together a simpler example.

Answer (score -2):

In standard mysql you'd "escape" the fields by using the ` character.

So for example:

```
select `query`.`date` from `query`
```

Try that and see if it works?

Comment: That throws a syntax error in ColdFusion.
```Lexical error at line 5, column 33. Encountered: "`" (96), after : ""```